# make a lookup function using javascript and bootstrap modal

Tags: codeigniter, modal-dialog, lookup

As my question above, how could I make a lookup function through bootstrap modal?

logic : click modal trigger -> launch modal -> select a row -> data row inserted to filed -> modal closed

[Here](http://pastebin.com/gCaUNmEC) is my code (it is for new tab opened, not BS modal).

Answer (score 0):

your understanding of a Bootstrap modal seems to be incorrect
you really don't need window.opener.parent and things like that because you are in the same dom tree as your main script - i hope it helps a bit

```
function pilih(row) {
    //        mendapatkan id perusahaan
    var perusahaanid = row.cells[1].innerHTML;

    //        mendapatkan nama perusahaan
    var nama= row.cells[2].innerHTML;

    //        memasukkan nama perusahaan dalam form
    $("#nama_perusahaan").value = nama;
    $("#id_perusahaan").value = id_perusahaanid ;
    //        menutup pop up
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");

}
```

Comment: Yes, i mean this script was work for window opener
now how to modify it for modal